# manyone field with my own default value, Odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-14

I have the `sale.order` model which has the `partner_shipping_id.country_id` field of the `res.country` model, what I want is to know how to have a new many2one field (res.country) but that has the `sale_order.partner_shipping_id.country_id` field loaded by default .

I have tried two ways without being able to get the result:

```
def _default_country_edit(self):
    return self.partner_shipping_id.country_id

country_edit = fields.Many2one('res.country', string="País", default=lambda self: self._default_country_edit())
```

or:

```
country_edit = fields.Many2one('res.country', string="País", default=_default_country_edit())
```

I need something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I did is in the `read` method, if you don't have the new field set it and that's it

```
if not self.country_edit:
   self.country_edit = self.partner_shipping_id.country_id
```

Obviously, in the write method, the `sale_order.partner_shipping_id.country_id` field must be set with the new one.